# Remove last added value from array without mutating it

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, immutability

```
dontMutateMeArray=[1,2,3,3,3,4,5];
toBeRemoved=3;

newArray=dontMutateMeArray.something(toBeRemoved);          // [1,2,3,3,4,5]  
iDontWantArray=dontMutateMeArray.filter(value=>value===toBeRemoved);  // [1,2,4,5]
```

I indeed need it for array of objects too. And I specifically need to **remove the last added object** *(ie. the one with higher index in the array)*. Something like:

```
dontMutateMeArray=[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3,sth:1},{id:3,sth:42},{id:3,sth:5},{id:4},{id:5}];
toBeRemoved=3;

newArray=dontMutateMeArray.something(toBeRemoved);          // [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3,sth:1},{id:3,sth:42},{id:4},{id:5}]  
iDontWantArray=dontMutateMeArray.filter(obj=>obj.id===toBeRemoved);  // [{id:1},{id:2},{id:4},{id:5}]
iDontWantArray2=dontMutateMeArray.blahBlah(toBeRemoved);    // [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3,sth:1},{id:3,sth:5},{id:4},{id:5}]
```

Comment: This is not clear, can you clarify what your after here?

Comment: By last added do you mean the last item in the array or the item most recently added in time?

Comment: If your goal is to use methods like `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, etc without mutating the original, I would suggest [lodash](https://lodash.com)/[underscore](http://underscorejs.org). I tend to use them over the built in methods anyways.

Comment: What do you mean by "last added object"? How do you know which of these objects is the "last added" one?

Comment: i want to remove the one with the higher index in array, not a random object with `id==toBeRemoved`;

Comment: @Liam what's not clear? I've provided input, output, what needs to be done to obtain the output, what I've tried and what I don't want. What else do you expect? I shall provide additional details if I know the same...

Comment: Then why was `{id:3,sth:42}` removed in your last example, and not `{id:3,sth:5}`? `{id:3,sth:5}` comes after `{id:3,sth:42}`.

Comment: :D bcoz that was assigned to `iDontWantArray2` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate from right and check with a closure.

```js
var dontMutateMeArray = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3, sth: 1 }, { id: 3, sth: 42 }, { id: 3, sth: 5 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }],
    toBeRemoved = 3,
    newArray = dontMutateMeArray.reduceRight((found => (r, a) => (!found && a.id === toBeRemoved ? found = true : r.unshift(a), r))(false), []);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: simple and elegant one liner avoiding the use of a another variable outside reducer's scope :)